# _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString; does not work in multiple calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i am facing this issue actually i am calling one controller from an other. like this

```
foreach (var PatientNotesId in notesIdVM.CollectionPatientNotesId)
            {
                CCDAPatientController cCDAPatientController = new 
                  CCDAPatientController(_context, 
                _contextMain, _configuration);
                cCDAPatientController.ControllerContext = this.ControllerContext;
                cCDAPatientController.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);
                FilePaths = (cCDAPatientController.GetCCDAForPatient(PatientNotesId, null, 
                Folderpath));
                
            }
```

in CCDAPatientController  in OnActionExecuting method i am getting some values

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionDetails)
        {
            if (User != null)
            {
                UD = VMCommon.GetLoginUserInfo(_contextMain,
                       User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email)).Value,
                       User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("Role", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Value);
                Email = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email)).Value;
                connectionString = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
               
                practiceId = Convert.ToInt64(User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("RandomKEY", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Value);
                temp = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("TEMP", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Value;

            }

        }
```

the connectionstring which i am getting on first call is perfect but on 2nd call to controller in foreach loop the connection string has password missing in it.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the password add:

```
Persist Security Info=true
```

To your connection string

Comment: its multi tenancy application. i am getting connection string of the current login user..
connection string is not written in appsetting.json.. then how can i make presist security info =true??